# Changing Link Attributes for Wp_Link_Pages

Tags: php, pagination

I'm wondering if there is any way to change the actual link itself for wp_link_pages. So right now, I have a simple code to display the pagination for a post, it looks like this:

`<?php wp_link_pages( array( 'before' => '<div class="link-pages">' . __('Pages:', 'muimedia'), 'after' => '</div>',) ); ?>`

It displays the Post pagination like so:

Pages: 1 2 3

Page one links two page one, page two links to page 2 etc. Now, I would like to add an attribute called `fromwhere=news"` to the pagination permalinks. So page 1, 2, and 3 pagination links would look like so.. `mysite.com/somepost/post?fromwhere=news"` instead of just `mysite.com/somepost/post`

I really hope this is possible, and if anyone could help me out, it would really mean a lot to me! And happy new years!!! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no filter for the URLs, and no filter for the complete output of `wp_link_pages()`. But you can get the output as string if you pass `'echo' => FALSE` as argument.

There are four options:

1. Write a modified copy of the function with the URLs you need. You will miss all further improvements which may happen in core code.
2. Catch the output in a string and run a regex on that. Example:

   ```
   print preg_replace(
       '~(href=")([^"]+)~',
       '\1\2?from=' . $post->post_name,
       wp_link_pages( array ( 'echo' => FALSE ) )
   );
   ```
3. [Use JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3521561/299509) to add the parameter.
4. Do nothing. Do not offer the same content – separate sub pages – with different URLs (a search result could link to a sub page too), and make external search engines like Google happy.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I agree that your answers are great starting points, but I honestly have no idea how to make your answers work unfortunately . Regarding number 2, how would I make this work?  I know how to do this with custom fields, that's not hard.  But the complicated part is adding the ?fromwhere=news" to the end of the URL. Do you think you could help me out with an answer to add the fromwhere to the end of the pagination links via your number 2 answer (or maybe even number 3)?  It would really mean a lot. :)

Comment: @user1936894 I had an error in my first explanation: You don’t need an output buffer. And I added an example showing how to change the URLs with a regex.

Comment: your updated answer (number 2) worked like a charm, thanks a lot!!! :)