# Remove Spaces From WP_LINK_PAGES

Tags: wp-link-pages

By default, wp_link_pages (the code which allows you to breakup posts into multiple pages) creates spaces between each number.  Is there a way to remove these spaces via functions.php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace `a> <a` with `a><a`:

```
echo str_replace( 'a> <a', 'a><a', wp_link_pages( array ( 'echo' => FALSE ) ) );
```

If you want to remove the spaces around unlinked numbers too, I suggest a separate function in your theme’s `functions.php` to keep the code readable:

```
function trimmed_link_pages( $args = array () )
{
    $args['echo'] = FALSE;
    $links = wp_link_pages( $args );
    $links = str_replace(
        array ( 'a> ', ' <a', ':<a' ),
        array ( 'a>',  '<a',  ': <a' ),
        $links
    );
    print $links;
}
```

Use it like `wp_link_pages()`:

```
if ( have_posts() )
{
    while ( have_posts() )
    {
        the_post();
        print '<h2><a href="' . get_permalink() . '">' . get_the_title() . '</a></h2>';
        the_content();
        trimmed_link_pages();
    }
}
```

Related: [Changing Link Attributes for Wp_Link_Pages](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/77845/73).

Comment: That doesn't seem to be working for me, are you simply adding this to functions.php?

Comment: I am using this instead of the naked `wp_link_pages()` in a theme. The function does not provide an output filter unfortunately.

Comment: Out of curiosity, any idea how to remove the spaces around the current page also... since it is not linked?

Comment: Thanks, but I actually can't get that new function to work for whatever reason.  With my limited PHP knowledge, I assume it should work.  How would you implement it?

Comment: @siouxfan45 See my update. Tested, works.